# Change to Marshall

Tags: discussion, badges

Looks as if the marshall flag was changed from a flag weight to a set number of raised flags.  I was pretty close, well, 150ish, away from achieving this badge.  After the change now, I'm no where close.  This isn't a whine thread, but I was just wondering what constituted the change to use only helpful flags.  Was there a fundamental flaw to the weight system?

Comment: Bear in mind that the flag weight gains decreased as you gained weighting: I've raised 174 flags, with a score of 669ish. At 600 you would still have had a *long* way to go. I like that it's a tangible goal now, rather than seemingly insurmountable task previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the change was to focus on the number of helpful flags rather than flag weight. In the end, I think it works out to be pretty much the same.

[Change the requirements for the Marshal badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106627/change-the-requirements-for-the-marshal-badge)